# NumberPicker displaying incorrect value

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an issue with the NumberPicker with custom values. When opening the dialog, I fetch the value to display in the NumberPicker by finding its index in the array of custom values and setting the Value of the NumberPicker to this index. Tracing shows that the correct index is found and set in NumberPicker.Value; however, the NumberPicker shows the value of a different index.

In the attached image, I have a value of 1/4 but it shows as 1/45. If I select a value of 1/6, it will show as 1/60. A value of 1, shows up as 1/1000. 
If I select it, the correct index is held in the NumberPicker.Value so I get the desired value back, it is just that the display is confused and seems to pick something closely matching the desired value (1/45 for 1/4, 1/60 for 1/6, etc.) and ignoring the index in the array that I set. 
If I select a value of 2, 3, etc. the correct value shows in the NumberPicker.

Below is the the relevant code, the issue is both in simulator and on a real Android device.

```
public class MeasuredExposureDialog : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
{
private ReciprocityAdapter _mAdapter = null;

private string[] shutterSpeeds = { "1/1000", "1/750", "1/500", "1/350", "1/180", "1/125", "1/90", "1/60", "1/45", "1/30", "1/20", "1/15", "1/10", "1/8", "1/6", **"1/4"**, "1/3", "1/2", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
    , "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"
    , "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70"
    , "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100"
    , "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130"
    , "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160"
    , "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190"
    , "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220"
};

public static MeasuredExposureDialog NewInstance(Bundle bundle)
{
    MeasuredExposureDialog fragment = new MeasuredExposureDialog();
    fragment.Arguments = bundle;
    return fragment;
}

public ReciprocityAdapter Adapter
{
    set{ _mAdapter = value; }
}

public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = Activity.LayoutInflater;

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.numberpicker, null);
        builder.SetView(view);
        builder.SetTitle("Measured exposure");

        NumberPicker numberPicker = view.FindViewById<NumberPicker>(Resource.Id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.MaxValue = shutterSpeeds.Length - 1;
        numberPicker.MinValue = 0;
        numberPicker.SetDisplayedValues(shutterSpeeds);
        numberPicker.WrapSelectorWheel = true;

        string value = _mAdapter.GetEntrySetting(4);

        Log.Info("myapp", "Setting stored value: " + value);

        for (int i = 0; i < shutterSpeeds.Length; i++)
        {
            if (shutterSpeeds[i] == value)
            {
                numberPicker.Value = i;
                Log.Info("myapp", "Setting value to index: " + i);
                break;
            }
        }

        //numberPicker.ClearFocus();

        // Add action buttons
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Select", (senderAlert, args) = >
        {
            _mAdapter.SetEntry(4, shutterSpeeds[numberPicker.Value]);
            _mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) = >
        {
        });

        return builder.Create();
    }
}
```

The adapter code:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Reciprocity.Fragments
{
public class ReciprocityAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private View _itemView = null;
    private List<Entry> _entryList;

    public string GetEntrySetting(int position)
    {
        return _entryList[position].setting;
    }

    public void StoreEnvironment()
    {
        //store
        var prefs = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Reciprocity2", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();

        if (_entryList[0].setting != "Tap to select a film")
            prefEditor.PutString("selectedFilm", _entryList[0].setting);

        prefEditor.PutString("measuredSeconds", _entryList[4].setting);

        prefEditor.PutBoolean("useBGR", true);

        prefEditor.PutString("filterFactor", _entryList[1].setting);
        prefEditor.PutString("lensExtension", _entryList[3].setting);
        prefEditor.PutString("focalLength", _entryList[2].setting);

        prefEditor.Commit();
    }

    public void RestoreEnvironment()
    {
        var prefs = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Reciprocity2", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var selectedFilm = prefs.GetString("selectedFilm", null);

        if (selectedFilm != null)
        {
            _entryList[0].setting = selectedFilm;
        }

        _entryList[4].setting = prefs.GetString("measuredSeconds", "Tap to select");
        _entryList[1].setting = prefs.GetString("filterFactor", "Tap to select");
        _entryList[3].setting = prefs.GetString("lensExtension", "Tap to select");
        _entryList[2].setting = prefs.GetString("focalLength", "Tap to select");
    }

    public ReciprocityAdapter(List<Entry> entries)
    {
        _entryList = entries;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        // Inflate the CardView for the photo:
        _itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.cardview, parent, false);

        // Create a ViewHolder to hold view references inside the CardView:
        ReciprocityViewHolder vh = new ReciprocityViewHolder(_itemView, OnClick);

        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ReciprocityViewHolder vh = holder as ReciprocityViewHolder;

        vh.category.Text = _entryList[position].category;
        vh.setting.Text = _entryList[position].setting;

        vh.image.SetImageResource(_entryList[position].colorbar);
        vh.image.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);

        CardView cv = vh.ItemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cv);
        cv.SetCardBackgroundColor((position == 5) ? Color.Yellow : Color.White);
    }

    private void OnClick(int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
            ItemClick(this, position);
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _entryList.Count;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
}

public class ReciprocityViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView image { get; private set; }
    public TextView category { get; private set; }
    public TextView setting { get; private set; }

    public ReciprocityViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener)
        : base(itemView)
    {
        image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.colorBar);
        setting = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.reciprocitySetting);
        category = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.reciprocityCategory);

        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.AdapterPosition);
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The output is the following:

```
Setting stored value: 1/4
Setting value to index: 15
```

The way it shows up in the dialog:

[image: screen]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Does this match your problems? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882051/numberpicker-showing-wrong-value-after-setvalue?rq=1

Comment: Could you please post your complete code ?

Comment: I've added the complete code, note that this occurs in the OnCreateDialog, no manual data in inputted.

Comment: Timothy, the issue description is similar, the suggested solution doesn't seem to be applicable in my case as I do not use an ontouch handler

Comment: Please post your `ReciprocityAdapter`'s code, when I dont use it all works fine.

Comment: @york-shen I added the adapter code, I use it for a cardview in a RecyclerView; in the dialog I use it to fetch the data I want to change.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share a simple demo to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Here is a short video that I just recorded on my Android (7.0) phone that shows the issue: https://youtu.be/f9JQ6yaMMt4

Comment: It's a little difficult to reproduce your problem, would you mind sharing your basic demo? to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.